# Perl: How to copy directory without any files?

Tags: perl

I would like to copy one folder with subfolders but without the files. With `dircopy` from package `File::Copy::Recursive` the whole structure with the files will be copied:

```
my $source = 'C:/dir_source';
my $target = 'C:/dir_target';

dircopy $source, $target or die "Could not perform dircopy of $source to $target: $!";
```

Is there an appropriate module or do I have use `finddepth` from module `use File::Find;` and use rmdir?

Comment: So you want to duplicate a directory structure but ignore all files? That's an interesting requirement. I don't see File::Copy::Recursive being able to do that. It might be easiest to use File::Find::Rule to build this yourself. Faster and nicer than deleting files again.

Comment: Not sure if the code is generic, but https://theweeklychallenge.org/ does something similar in their maintenance script. Have a look at their github, I'm not sure which file it is, but there should be a script that initialises a new weekly challenge folder. It preps every participant's folder with all the language folders they've done before, but no files. But they may have hardcoded it.

Comment: something like `use File::Find; chdir $orig; find({ no_chdir=>1, wanted=>sub{ return if -f; print "mkdir $new/$_\n"}, ".")'` ?

Comment: `rsync` with simple file exclusion might work too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about libraries; some probably exist which can be coerced into giving you that.

Here's one way to do it, indeed using [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) to find the hierarchy.  Then go through that list of full-path locations and make them

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find;

sub get_dir_hier {
    my ($src) = @_; 

    my @dirs;
    find( sub { 
        push @dirs, $File::Find::name 
            if -d and $File::Find::name ne $src;  # only UNDER source dir
    }, $src); 

    return \@dirs;
}

sub copy_dir_hier {
    my ($dirs, $tgt, $verbose) = @_; 

    for my $dir (@$dirs) {
        next if not $dir;

        say "mkdir $tgt/$dir" if $verbose;
        # mkdir "$tgt/$dir"                    # UNCOMMENT AFTER TESTING
        #    or warn "Error with mkdir $tgt/$dir: $!";
    }   
}

my ($source_dir, $target_dir) = @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 source-dir target-dir\n" 
    if not $source_dir or not $target_dir;

say "Copy directory hierarchy from under $source_dir to under $target_dir\n";

say "Find directory hierarchy under $source_dir"; 
my $dirs = get_dir_hier($source_dir);
say for @$dirs; say '-'x60;

say "\nCopy that hierarchy under $target_dir";
copy_dir_hier( $dirs, $target_dir, 1 );
```

This obtains the listing of directories *under* the given source directory, without it; that is easily changed.  Then those are copied under the target directory, which isn't made.

For making directories, the target directory (under which to make the hierarch) must exist for `mkdir` to work, since it doesn't create directories recursively; the source's directory hierarchy is built by adding them in order so that is not a problem for the rest of hierarchy.

In order to create paths (recursively) see `make_path` in [File::Path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Path)

*All code shown here has been tested and it works as it stands but it needs a lot more testing.*

---

One other way is by using the Linux `tree` command.

The `tree` command can be made into printing directories only, with the full path and without pretty graphics: `tree -dfi`. With these options the default output of

```
$ tree t1
t1
├── f1.txt
├── t21
│   ├── f21a.txt
│   ├── f21.txt
│   └── t31
│       └── f3.txt
└── t22
```

turns into

```
$ tree -dfi t1
t1
t1/t21
t1/t21/t31
t1/t22
```

This is a convenient form for making those directories.

Here's a (barely-tested) code for finding the directory hierarchy this way:

```
# Uses "tree" command
sub get_dir_hier_using_tree {
    my ($src) = @_;

    my @out = qx(tree -dfi $src);

    my @dirs = grep { m{^/|\.} } @out;  #/ keep only directories (full path)
    chomp @dirs;
    #say for @dirs; say '---';

    # Remove the leading part of the path, to the source-directory name
    s{^$src/?}{} for @dirs;

    # Remove possibly empty entries
    @dirs = grep { defined and /\S/ } @dirs;
    #say for @dirs; say '-'x40;

    return \@dirs
}
```